# Use sh script or Python to find & delete all directories prefixed with a specific string that are older than 3 days but ignore unique results

Tags: python, shell, unix, sh, esxi

As the title suggests, I am looking to find all directories that are prefixed with a string of "LB".
For the most part, all directories will generally have a suffix of "_[0-9]", as each day a new directory gets created by a bespoke backup process. E.g:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Mar  5 10:00 TB-setcluster
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Mar  6 10:00 TB-setcluster_1
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Mar  7 10:00 TB-setcluster_2
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Mar  8 10:00 TB-setcluster_3
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Mar  8 13:02 TB-drycluster_3
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Mar  8 13:02 TB-drycluster_2
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Mar  8 13:02 TB-drycluster_1
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Mar  8 13:02 TB-drycluster
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Mar  5 13:02 TB-testcluster
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Mar  5 13:02 TB-preprod-cluster
```

That said, if any backup fails, I will not get an incremental directory created, which means I could potentially end up in the scenario that I only have one backup if the following 3 days worth of backups were to fail.
In this event I do not want to delete the one copy that I may have.

Can anyone suggest the best way of doing this? I am running on an ESXI box which is a cut down Linux kernel, and therefore only have bourne shell to script this with, or maybe python (of which I have a little bit of knowledge).

I have a find command that gets the output of the unique names by running:

```
find /root/test/ -depth -name "TB*" -type d -mtime 3| sort  | awk -F'/' '{print $4}' | sed -r 's/_[0-9]+$//g' | uniq -u
```

But I am unsure how I would then ensure that each result from the above command is excluded from any removal process.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this and I wanted to be sure, I might

1. use the above `find` command to move all the precious files to another directory

   mv $(find ... | awk ... | sed ... | uniq ... ) special_directory
2. do a careful visual inspection
3. remove everything that remained